# Linux awk sort descending order not working

Tags: linux, sorting, awk

I have two files that I need to sort with.

**The command I'm using is:**

```
cat first-in.txt | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d '/' -f 3 | cut -d '^' -f 1 | sort -b -t . -k 1,1nr -k 2,2nr -k 3,3r -k 4,4r -k 5,5r | uniq > first-out.txt


cat second-in.txt | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d '/' -f 3 | cut -d '^' -f 1 | sort -b -t . -k 1,1nr -k 2,2nr -k 3,3r -k 4,4r -k 5,5r | uniq > second-out.txt
```

the issue is:
I need to sort CORRECTLY in descending order, because right now, only file 2 is sorting correctly, but file 1 is not sorting correctly.

i would like to know the mistake i am making

**Files**

[All files are here including output are here](https://gist.github.com/itsbalamurali/8236527)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: List the first and second file, and how you like to output to be.  This `cat first-in.txt | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d '/' -f 3 | cut -d '^' -f 1` could be change to `awk '{split($2,a,"/");split(a[3],b,"^");print b[1]}' first-in.txt | sort...`

Comment: @Jotne [First file](https://gist.github.com/itsbalamurali/8236527#file-first-in) , [Second file](https://gist.github.com/itsbalamurali/8236527#file-second-in) and out has to be like [Output](https://gist.github.com/itsbalamurali/8236527#file-second-out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean this is wrong:

```
4.2.4
4.2.3
4.2.20
4.2.2
```

You want `4.2.20` to be higher than all of those, right?

You can fix that by change the `-k` param of `sort` to treat all fields as numeric:

```
.... -k 1,1nr -k 2,2nr -k 3,3nr -k 4,4nr -k 5,5nr ....
```

Answer (score 1):

On *GNU/Linux* system you could use *sort* with the *-V* option:

```
sed -r 's|.*/([^/^]*).*$|\1|' infile | sort -Vr
```

Note that both *sed -r* and *sort -V* are not standard.